# N2600 and Ubuntu 14.04 is slow

Tags: 14.04

My new laptop has an Intel N2600 processor, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and it is soooo slow. What is wrong? Is there any help?  Or can I use only windows on this machine?

Comment: Could you please tell us what is slow, and other hardware details?

Comment: When i open something it does not go smooth and films are  also not smoot and to build up a page takes seconds.  I have 2 G Ram  and a  320  G harddisk.   Also when i write it is very slow. Windows works well only ubuntu is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try using gnome desktop instead of unity, you select it at the login screen by clicking the icon.

Comment: Where can I find the login screen?

Comment: Why to use `gnome` instead of `unity` ?; however `xfce` and `lxde` is lightweight not `gnome` (Also this doesn't provide answer it seems commentary only!)

Comment: I suggested using gnome (perhaps I should have been more complete and said gnome-metacity) as it is less resource intensive, and runs smoother and snapier, than unity on lower spec machines. I know this for a fact as I have set up many low spec machines and none of them run unity as they don't have decent graphics cards. Using gnome gives an instant performane boost. LXDE and XFCE are, as said, lightweight. I run LXDE on my Aspire One and it is snappy and responsive. I'm trying to help, and as "Heinz" doesn't know where the login screen is I think some hand holding might be required here.

Comment: The login screen is where you enter your password to login to the computer. (I will use comments instead of answers in future as requested.....my mistake :) )